# Javascript speechrecognition API

Tags: javascript

Could someone please take a look at my code and tell me what im doing wrong? when you click submit im looking for the speech to convert into a string and write this on the html.
Also im looking to do things with certain words, so for example if the speech matches "test" do something! But what if this is read as "text" I want a error section to say "did you mean test"

```
 var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition;
 var returnedSpeech=[];
 recognition.onresult = function(event) {

  if (event.results.length > 0) {
    speech.value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
    speech.form.submit();
    var x=speech.value
    document.write(x.value)

  }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, the examples given are pretty clear ( https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API ). You're probably getting an error in console from `new webkitSpeechRecognition` as it should be `new webkitSpeechRecognition()`

Comment: Thank you for your help